# error in mysql & after installed Laravel in docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I installed successfully install Bitnami/Laravel

how to use MySQL in Docker?
I run localhost:3306 but it's not running
any ideas

Comment: what's your container configuration?

Comment: Can you show the logs?

Answer (score 0):

check your network, mysql container in same network with laravel container
and use container name for example mysql container name is db you can in laravel
env variables db:3306

Answer (score 0):

Use the network name of MySQL in the `.env` file.
For example, if the network name of MySQL is `mysql_docker`, add this to the `.env`:

```
DB_HOST=mysql_docker
DB_PORT=3306
```

Make sure you are using the correct port.
An example of MySQL configuration in the `docker-compose`:

```
 mysql_docker:
    image: mariadb:10.7.1
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql_container_name
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database_name
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```